# SDL2: Multiple renderers for multithreading is thread safe?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

If I create 4 windows with SDL2, each window has a renderer and is refreshed in 4 separate threads, will there be any thread safety issues?

Comment: Depends on if the data that these threads render is shared and if access of it is synchronised.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/CategoryThread